# How to create a double navbar which appears on scroll as in the link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to create two navbars.one will appear on the top and the other will appear as a content header below the first navbar and when we scroll the first navbar will disappear and the other will take place of the first one the example is given in the below link but I am not able to figure it out

**Link**: https://gadgets.ndtv.com/samsung-galaxy-m30s-price-in-india-91066

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: w3schools has instructions on how to do just that: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

Answer (score 1):

I made this code for you, hope you like it!
Ps: I edited the code to a shorter version!

```js
const header=document.querySelector(".header[handleScrolling]");
window.headerOffsetY=header.offsetTop+header.offsetHeight;

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
 document.querySelector("#scrollPoint").innerHTML=scrollY;
  scrollY>=headerOffsetY?header.classList.add("scrollEffects"):header.classList.remove("scrollEffects");
});
```

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0; padding: 0; cursor: default; font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.something{
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.header .tab{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 15px 12px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}
.header .tab:hover{
  color: #1848ff;
}
.header .tab.active{
  color: #1848ff;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1848ff;
}
.header.scrollEffects{
  position: fixed !important;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
  
   <body>
     
     <div class="something">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat repudiandae recusandae impedit eius in assumenda architecto at maiores! Incidunt commodi sapiente laborum, magnam voluptate libero blanditiis doloribus molestiae officiis nihil!
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat repudiandae recusandae impedit eius in assumenda architecto at maiores! Incidunt commodi sapiente laborum, magnam voluptate libero blanditiis doloribus molestiae officiis nihil!
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat repudiandae recusandae impedit eius in assumenda architecto at maiores! Incidunt commodi sapiente laborum, magnam voluptate libero blanditiis doloribus molestiae officiis nihil!
     </div>
     
     <div class="header" handleScrolling>
       
       <div class="tab active" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">Home
       </div><div class="tab" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">Reviews
       </div><div class="tab" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">Price
       </div><div class="tab" onclick="alert(this.innerHTML)">Videos
       </div><div class="tab" id="scrollPoint">0
       </div>
       
     </div>
     
     <div class="something">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic quae facere inventore impedit. Perspiciatis illo eaque numquam, soluta atque omnis corrupti unde at consequatur harum. Quia natus tempore ullam reprehenderit?
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatibus in adipisci doloremque assumenda molestiae illo debitis numquam soluta iure voluptate dignissimos ab eius, magnam, quis quos repudiandae suscipit voluptatum voluptatem.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nesciunt veniam, corporis, quae fugit ratione, eaque aspernatur quasi laboriosam quam dolorem nemo, voluptatum harum! Illum, culpa molestiae aspernatur at dignissimos.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci dolorum, non molestiae voluptatibus, eligendi consequuntur, sint amet, praesentium odit maiores soluta velit porro debitis rem itaque tempora! Itaque, iste, nulla.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Inventore fugit necessitatibus vel ipsa quia obcaecati nobis officia, eaque est voluptates illum unde temporibus, cumque excepturi harum eius ducimus veritatis. Sapiente.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex voluptate voluptates doloremque recusandae quae, adipisci iusto nisi ducimus eum illum maxime et, optio perspiciatis? Accusantium nam delectus libero officiis, officia.
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt omnis error quasi aliquid soluta nesciunt, rerum aspernatur fugit cupiditate tenetur dolor! Ad deserunt, repellat doloribus distinctio, molestiae nemo fuga officiis.
     </div>
     
   </body>
  
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Adane Are your answer perfectly fit in for me and successfuly worked

Comment: You are welcome!